# How can I convert the output of a for loop into a string?

Tags: python

I'm tasked with creating a "Caesar Cipher" that takes two inputs (a string for the message, and an integer for the shift) and returns a string that's just the input string with all of its characters shifted by the amount specified in the shift argument for each character in the string (including punctuation marks, special characters and capital letters).

I've made this... and it works, but the output displays like the output of a for loop when I need it to be a string. How can I convert it back into a string on a single line?

```
message = input("What is your message?")
shift = input("What is your shift?")
shift = int(shift)
for i in message:
    result = ((ord(i))+shift)
    print(chr(result))
```

TERMINAL

```
What is your message?hello
What is your shift?3
k
h
o
o
r
```

Comment: You can use a variable to hold your message like `full_message = ""`, and instead of printing, you can do `full_message += str(result)` to build up your message.  Then outside of your loop you can print it out via `print(full_message)`

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
message = input("What is your message?")
shift = input("What is your shift?")
shift = int(shift)
final_message = ''
for i in message:
    result = ((ord(i))+shift)
    char = chr(result)
    final_message += char
    print(char)

print(final_message)
```

Comment: Don't use `+=` repeatedly on strings. It's very inefficient. Use a list and `join()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use (generator) comprehension to simplify the loop, and use `join` to make a string:

```py
message = input("What is your message? ")
shift = int(input("What is your shift? "))

result = ''.join(chr(ord(c) + shift) for c in message)
print(result)
```

Example:

```
What is your message? hello
What is your shift? 3
khoor
```

---

If you do want to use `for`, you can do instead:

```py
result = []
for c in message:
    result.append(chr(ord(c) + shift))
result = ''.join(result)
```

That is, store the intermediate values in a list, and then combine them once the loop is finished.